# Need two solution for fast algorithms

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, performance

I got a bids table (different users). each user can place his bids (unlimited) whenever he wants to.

I need to apply two rules that should cancel bids:
first rule - no more than 4 consecutive bids , which means if the user have:
10.50
10.47
10.36
10.20
10.00
so 10.00 should be canceled.

second rule is no more than 9 bids among top 50 bids, again, the 10th should be canceled.

I do it the really long way, just running on the bids table and counting for consecutives. But I would like to know if someone has other idea... (php + mysql)

Thanks

Comment: Please give more detailed criteria of consecutiveness. Only decremental, or incremental too? Is 10 11 9 8 7 consecutive?

Comment: consecutives of the first criteria are only one after another without any other user's bid inbetween. it doesn't matter if 1 cents or 50 cents seperates these, it still count as consecutive.

Answer (score 0):

For the second criteria:

```
SELECT username, count(*) as bids
FROM 
  (SELECT username
  FROM bids
  ORDER BY bid_timestamp DESC
  LIMIT 50)
WHERE username = :username
GROUP BY username
HAVING COUNT(*) > :bid_limit
```

If this record returns any rows, then disallow the new bid. Probably a better way to do this but it's better than returning all 50 rows to php and then iterating through and counting.

Comment: The thing is need to cancel the lower one of the pack. is having 9 bids, and then bid another amount that is higher than the lowest of the 9 bids, then the 9th should be canceled and the new bid is ok...